# Insert new cells in TableView

Tags: objective-c, uitableview, xcode5

I have the following table for example.

[image]

I want to create a rule:

1. If the current cell is orange, insert a new red cell after it.
2. Insert a new red cell between every 2 different color cells.
3. Don't insert a red cell if the current cell is yellow and the next cell is yellow.

For now, I did this:

```
 for (int i = 0; i<self.colors.count; i++) {

    SomeColor *currentItem = [self.colors objectAtIndex:i];

    if (currentItem.color != orange) {

            if (i+1 < self.colors.count) {
                nextItem = [self.colors objectAtIndex:i+2];
                if (nextItem.color != orange) {
                    [indexSet addIndex:i+1];
                    indPath  = [NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:i+1 inSection:0];
                    [inPathArr addObject:indPath];
                }else{
                    nextItem = [self.colors objectAtIndex:i+2];
                     NSLog(@"Next: %@",[nextItem.mRows objectAtIndex:0]);
                    [indexSet addIndex:i+2];
                    indPath  = [NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:i+2 inSection:0];
                    [inPathArr addObject:indPath];
                }

            }

        }
}
```

Thanks for any help!!!

Comment: Could you please clarify a bit? You did this and what happened? What did you get? What is wrong? Does it work somehow at all?

Comment: It works but I cant get it working as I want...... can you please help?